# Used SQLite DBHelper in my first app. App restarts when I click Register button after filling form

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am beginner. It is my first app project. After watching tutorial, I created this app to register user but it is Not working. Please help to find out the errors and how to correct them. Thanks

(following code is copied from android studio 5:Debug)

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLEtbRegister": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pk.edu.vu.agentpawnbroker, PID: 27838
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEtbRegister": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEtbRegister(IDINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOMATIC,First NameTEXT NOT NULL,Last NameTEXT NOT NULL,Registration DateTEXT NOT NULL,User IDTEXT NOT NULL,PasswordTEXT NOT NULL )
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (near "TABLEtbRegister": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEtbRegister(IDINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOMATIC,First NameTEXT NOT NULL,Last NameTEXT NOT NULL,Registration DateTEXT NOT NULL,User IDTEXT NOT NULL,PasswordTEXT NOT NULL ))
    #################################################################
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1058)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1743)
        at pk.edu.vu.agentpawnbroker.Database.DBHelper.onCreate(DBHelper.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
        at pk.edu.vu.agentpawnbroker.Database.DBHelper.addUser(DBHelper.java:50)
        at pk.edu.vu.agentpawnbroker.RegisterActivity.register(RegisterActivity.java:40)
            ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a line like this:

```
String create = "CREATE TABLE" + tablename + ........
```

In this line you did not, although you should place the appropriate spaces between string literals and table/column names, so your statement reads like this:

```
CREATE TABLEtbRegister(IDINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOMATIC,First NameTEXT NOT NULL,
Last NameTEXT NOT NULL,Registration DateTEXT NOT NULL,
User IDTEXT NOT NULL,PasswordTEXT NOT NULL )
```

Do you see the problems?

```
TABLEtbRegister
NameTEXT
NameTEXT
DateTEXT
IDTEXT
PasswordTEXT
```

the names of the table and the columns are concatenated with their data types.
In the create statement you must have spaces between them.
**Also** I see that you use for the columns names that contain spaces themselves. This is not allowed. 
You must enclose these names inside square brackets or backticks (ASCII code 096), like `[First Name]` 
Edit:
Change your create statement to:

```
private static final String  CREATE_TABLE_REGISTER =
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REGISTER + " (" + KEY_ID + 
    " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOMATIC, " + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
    KEY_LNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_REGDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
    KEY_USERID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL )";
```

But also change the names of the columns, like:

```
String KEY_FNAME = "[First Name]";
```

Comment: private static final String TABLE_REGISTER = "tbUsers";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_REGISTER = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_REGISTER + "("
+ KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOMATIC,"
+ KEY_FNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
+ KEY_LNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
+ KEY_REGDATE + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
+ KEY_USERID + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
+ KEY_PASSWORD + "TEXT NOT NULL )";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_REGISTER);

Comment: please see above my comment. It is copy paste of my code and spaces are already included and there are no spaces between column names, i used _ but no spaces. Thanks for being a quick helper

Comment: `KEY_FNAME` is not the name of the column but the name of the variable holding the name of the column. The column's name is `First Name`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a space between `CREATE TABLE` and `tbRegister(...`.  I presume you want your table to be called `tbRegister`.

Here's the [syntax](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).